# Can I test my in app subscriptions when app is only in internal testing track?

Tags: android, react-native-iap

I have:

- configured subscriptions

  - 2 products each 2 base plans - every plan is active
- license testers
- internal track testers
- have the same build number in internal track as in my Android studio
- I did release build and installed it to my device via `adb`
- same signing keys
- I can list my subscriptions by providing skus

But unfortunately, I still can't get over the error when doing purchase:

```
error {
  "message": "That item is unavailable.",
  "debugMessage": "",
  "code": "E_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE",
  "responseCode": 4
}
```

I'm using [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab-community/react-native-iap) library and this is my code(simplyfied):

```js
  const {subscriptions, currentPurchase, finishTransaction, getSubscriptions, getPurchaseHistory} = useIAP()

  const subscribe = async (productId: string, offerToken: string) => {
    console.log('product id', productId, 'offertoken', offerToken)
    try {
      await requestSubscription({
        sku: productId,
        ...(offerToken && {
          subscriptionOffers: [{sku: productId, offerToken}],
        }),
      })
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = purchaseUpdatedListener((purchase: Purchase) => {
      console.log('purchase', JSON.stringify(purchase, null, 2))
    })
    return () => {
      subscription.remove()
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = purchaseErrorListener((error: PurchaseError) => {
      console.log('error', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))
    })
    return () => {
      subscription.remove()
    }
  }, [])

  const finish = () => {
    if (currentPurchase) {
      finishTransaction({purchase: currentPurchase, isConsumable: false})
    }
  }

...

{subscriptions.map((subscription) =>
              subscription.subscriptionOfferDetails.map((offer) => (
                <Text
                  key={offer.basePlanId}
                  onPress={() => subscribe(subscription.productId, offer.offerToken)}
                >
                  {subscription.name}
                </Text>
              )),
            )}
```

- Do I have to release app to closed testing to be able to proceed with testing?
- Do I have something misconfigured?

Any tips&tricks welcomed

Answer (score 7):

...well...I found it (☝ ՞ਊ ՞)☝ ... in 2023 for testing subscription for Android you need these boxes to be ticked:

- ✅ you have one Google Account on the device
- ✅ your Google Account email is in licensed users - **Google Play Console > License testing**
- ✅ `your-app.aab` uploaded to internal track
- ✅ your Google Account is listed as a tester for the internal track - **Your App > Internal testing > Testers**
- ✅ you have accepted to be internal tester via link (from ☝)  <- *this was my problem* (ᗒᗣᗕ)՞
- ✅ you have configured subscriptions and at least one base plan is active

not needed:

- ❌ release in closed/production track
- ❌ release build (I can run it with metro in debug mode)
- ❌ your build is signed with the same keys as `your-app.aab` in store

Comment: This worked for me
only mistake i was doing is uploading my build into closed testing, thank you